Suddenly can't connect to outside from docker container
I have a docker container running a dotnet application on a CentOS server.
It uses the MySQL database on the server (using ip address 172.16.2.1).
The docker-compose file is:
version: '2.0'

services:

  app:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
    command: dotnet /opt/AccountServer/AccountServer.dll
    working_dir: /opt/AccountServer
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config:/usr/share/AccountServer
      - ./AccountServer:/opt/AccountServer
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
      - 8084:8084
      - 8085:8085
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "10"
    networks:
        accounts_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.2.2

networks:
    accounts_net:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.16.2.0/24

Suddenly, it has stopped working. I have been into the container, and can't ping or telnet to anything outside (using 172.16.2.1 or the actual IP address of the server).
I suspect iptables - the output of iptables -S is:
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-N DROP-lan
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 143,220,993,110,995 -m set --match-set f2b-cyrus-imap src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,220,993,110,995 -m set --match-set f2b-postfix-sasl src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m set --match-set f2b-sshd-ddos src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m set --match-set f2b-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m set --match-set snortsam_INGRESS src -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i pptp+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ebc86eceb8c2 ! -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ebc86eceb8c2 -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-dc50f27706ba -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o br-dc50f27706ba -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-dc50f27706ba ! -o br-dc50f27706ba -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-dc50f27706ba -o br-dc50f27706ba -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m set --match-set snortsam_SELF src,dst,dst -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m set --match-set snortsam_EGRESS dst -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m set --match-set snortsam_INGRESS src -j DROP
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12459 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp4s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12459 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp4s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.6/32 -o enp4s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i pptp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m set --match-set snortsam_SELF src,dst,dst -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m set --match-set snortsam_EGRESS dst -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o pptp+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.1.1.2/32 ! -i br-ebc86eceb8c2 -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.2/32 ! -i br-dc50f27706ba -o br-dc50f27706ba -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-dc50f27706ba -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o br-dc50f27706ba -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-ebc86eceb8c2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-ebc86eceb8c2 -o br-dc50f27706ba -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i br-dc50f27706ba -o br-ebc86eceb8c2 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DROP-lan -j DROP

But I haven't a clue which rule is the problem. Any suggestions for how to debug this?

The actual error message you receive could be a clue, along with the test command. it doesn't work is not a helpful description.

another piece of useful information is, what did you change to make it suddenly stop working? Computers rarely change how they work without something changing, and 99% of the time it's something changed by the user (e.g. an update of some kind)

Any attempt to connect to the database (even using telnet from bash inside the container) times out. Ping also doesn't get any packets back. I did say that any attempt to ping or telnet anything on the host fails.
I am not aware of changing anything!
